# Showing reviews only for products which are assigned to selected category

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have sub category which display all products assigned to it. I want to show all reviews which are belongs to only products in the selected category.

Example: when I open Sub category will show 2 products ( which are assigned to it ) then from table `reviews` I want to select all reviews for this products only

So far I have sub category and products. Now I'm wondering how to select those products reviews.

This is what I have in DualSubCategories model for relation with products

```
public function products()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Product', 'dual_sub_cat_id');
}
```

this is the function in my controller

```
public function showSubProducts($subcatId)
{

    $dual = DualSubCategories::where('sub_cat_id', $subcatId)->with('products')->get();

    return View::make('subcategory', [
        'dual' => $dual
    ]);
}
```

In table `reviews` I have column for `product_id`

I have added this in my DualSubCategories model in relation with reviews

```
public function reviews()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Review', 'product_id');
}
```

Then in the blade I've tried like this

```
@foreach($dual->reviews as $review)

 ...

@endforeach
```

This shows all reviews no matter what products are in category.

Comment: Have you tried anything? can you supply the code you have tried.

Comment: I've tried to add relation in the sub category model with reviews but then is showing all reviews no matter what products are in this sub category

Comment: Okay update your question with that code, That is something we may be able to help with.

Comment: I've added it to the question. But seems it's wrong because reviews are bound with products not with category

Comment: This still is not enough information. You need to show, The code both executed code plus the code to execute (if parameters are sent) and the sql query used. I suspect the problem is in the sql query not being provided enough information to filter results out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must eager load the product reviews not the sub category rewiews :

```
public function showSubProducts($subcatId)
{

    $dual = DualSubCategories::where('sub_cat_id', $subcatId)->with('products.reviews')->get();

    return View::make('subcategory', [
        'dual' => $dual
    ]);
}
```

In the view :

```
@foreach($dual->products as $product)
    @foreach($product->reviews as $review)

     ...

    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

And remove the relationship between sub category and reviews

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: Hm, actually it's showing only one review not all. So one product can have saved multiple reviews and must show all of them

Comment: It will show all of the product reviews, because you have a one to may relationship.